# Browser of windows phone. what browser use windows phone?

Tags: mobile, cross-browser, browser, windows-phone

what browser use windows phone? 
I need to know what is the technology that browser of windows phone use. To develope with compatibility's knowledge

Comment: you can get by googling ?

Comment: Surprisely I didn't find it

Comment: where did you look? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone#Web_browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone uses [Internet Explorer Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7.5+ uses a version of IE9; Windows Phone 8.0 uses IE10.